# Unsure On A Math TL

Tags: word-usage

I've a comment in a manga relating to the speed of a shock-wave passing through someone's stomach and I'm not sure I get what it's saying:

> 腹の直径は約1.5m
>
> 波のスピードは4km/s
>
> 腹の直線を1.5mとして割ると2.7秒となる

So the top two bits obviously say that the stomach is around 1.5m in diameter, and that the wave's speed is 4km/s, but I don't really follow what the latter bit's saying (I'd assume it's something like 2.7 seconds to cover the stomach or something, but that'd be way too slow presumably).

Comment: Replace "km/s" with "m/s" or seconds with milliseconds. How do you find it a Japanese language-related question?

Comment: Yes, 4/1.5 is almost 2.7 if we ignore the units, but there must be something *mathematically* wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you. I cannot understand these sentences. They seem illogical.

> 腹の直径は約1.5m

I don't know this sentence. It's too large for a human. Maybe the writer is talking about a whale or something.

> 波のスピードは4km/s

What kind of the wave? It is Mach 11.7. It's very faster than the sound's wave.
If it is the typo of 4km/hr, it would be near the walking speed of a person.

> 腹の直線を1.5mとして割ると2.7秒となる

It would be 0.375msec instead. If the wave's speed was 4km/hr, it would be 1.1m/sec, and the answer would be 1.35秒.

The context seems an ackamaraka. It isn't true, or more context and background should be needed to make a better answer for your question. This might be a language spoken/written by a schizophrenic patient. And I can think this is a language question, rather a math question. :)

Hope this helps.